# Why does this code cause a Floating point exception - SIGFPE

Tags: c, exception, compiler-optimization, gcc4

Using gcc 4.7:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.0 20120505 (prerelease)
```

Code listing (test.c):

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct test {
    int before;

    char start[0];
    unsigned int v1;
    unsigned int v2;
    unsigned int v3;
    char end[0];

    int after;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int x, y;

  x = ((uintptr_t)(&((struct test*)0)->end)) - ((uintptr_t)(&((struct test*)0)->start));
  y = ((&((struct test*)0)->end)) - ((&((struct test*)0)->start));

  return x + y;
}
```

Compile & execute

```
$ gcc -Wall -o test test.c && ./test
Floating point exception
```

The SIGFPE is caused by the second assignment (y = ...).  In the assembly listing, there is a division on this line?  Note that the only difference between x= and y= is casting to (uintptr_t).

Comment: GCC explorer output: http://preview.tinyurl.com/8ah2fa7

Comment: `char start[0];` means you're out of the territory defined by the standard. What happens beyond that, is it really so interesting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disregarding the undefined behaviour due to violation of constarints in the standard, what gcc does here is to calculate the difference between two pointers to `char[0]` - `&(((struct test*)0)->start)` and `&(((struct test*)0)->end)`, and divide that difference by the size of a `char[0]`, which of course is 0, so you get a division by 0.

Comment: And for historical reasons in UNIX an integer division by `0` yields a Floating point exception (SIGFPE signal)

Comment: Is that a UNIX (and derivatives) speciality? I thought it was an x86 thing.

Comment: Good question I know it is the case for x86 on UNIX but I'm not sure it is the case for other systems.

Comment: If anybody definitely knows, please ping @ouah too. I'd be interested to know for sure.

Comment: Tested integer division by `0` on a Linux armv6l, it also gives a Floating point exception.

Comment: @ouah It's a POSIX thing. `signal.h` defines `FPE_INTDIV` and `FPE_INTOVF` for use with `sigaction` when using `SA_SIGINFO` (`SIGFPE` is defined as _Erroneous arithmetic operation_). Also note that `SIGINT` has a different meaning, so anything resembling that could be confusing, and there are not many longish signal names.

Comment: @ouah: of course, the previous comment is true on systems that trap on integer divide by zero and/or integer overflow. Some systems may not do that, and I hope they are not required to send the corresponding signal.

Comment: @ninjalj I bet some UNIX systems with some more exotic processors could have undefined behavior on an asm `divide` by `0` instruction and couly actually respond randomly.

Comment: apparently on mips system the divide instruction does not trap on zero division and `gcc` will add extra code to check for `0` and trap on this processor. A SIGPFE will then be issued. (See the default `-mdivide-traps` option) By compiling with `-mno-check-zero-division` the extra check for `0` is disabled, the divide instruction will not trap and no signal SIGFPE will be sent, but the behavior of the program will be undefined.

Comment: Regarding C and POSIX requirements. C does not require the implementation to issue a SIGFPE signal (on an integer division by zero for example) *(C11, 7.11p4) "An implementation need not generate any of these signals, except as a result of explicit calls to the raise function"* and this is the same for POSIX: see this POSIX accepted resolution defect that clarifies the situation: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=536